# Перемещение JFrame c setUndecorated(true) при помощи мышки

Tags: java, swing

Если я использую

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы можно было перемещать форму мышкой?

Comment: Через события мышки. `MouseMotionAdapter`, в нем есть методы `mouseMoved`, `mouseDragged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо создать слушатель и повесить его на окно:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();

MouseAdapter m = new MouseAdapter() {
    int y;
    int x;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // запоминаем координаты клика 
        x = e.getX(); 
        y = e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // двигаем окно 
        f.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen() - x, e.getYOnScreen() - y);
    }
};

f.setSize(300,200);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setUndecorated(true);
f.addMouseMotionListener(m);
f.addMouseListener(m);
f.setVisible(true);
```